# URL trouble to pass parameter

Tags: python, django, url

This link can not pass parameter to view.py

```
<a href="edit/{{costumer.slug}}"> profile</a>
```

It gives an error  page not found,  127.0.0.1:8000/profile/edit/
There is not parameter there, even {{costumer.slug}} returns a string

Rest of template has no porblem to pass a parameter like this:

```
 <a href="editjob/{{j.id}}/"> {{j.title}}</a>
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Seems like a typo, shouldn't it be `customer` and not `costumer`? Unless you're building something for people who makes costumes.

Comment: there has been written "costumer" all the way, so it shouldn't be the reason, but sorry it is a typo

Comment: and doing this `<a href="">{{costumer.slug}}</a>` shows the slug?

Comment: yes it shows the slug

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are missing a leading slash, so the browser is concatenating the URL with the one you're already on (you're on '/profile', you click 'edit', you go to '/profile/edit').

But you shouldn't be building up URLs like that. You should use the `url` tag. Assuming your URLconf is this:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', 'profile.views.edit_profile', name='edit_profile')
```

you would do this in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_profile' slug=costumer.slug %}">
```

Comment: this line gives an syntex error
url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', 'profile.views.edit_profile', name='edit_profile')

Comment: That was just an example. But there's nothing wrong with that syntax. Where did you put it?

Comment: (r'^edit/(?P<slug>\w+)/$','edit', name='edit_profile'), that is what i wrote, it says "Syntax error while detecting tuple"

Comment: Well, then you haven't used what I wrote, you're missing the `url` at the beginning which makes this a function call rather than a tuple.